# Does Maxwell's demon include the knowledge of the experimenter?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, maxwell-equations, information

We know Leo Szilard was right when he said the demon would need to expend energy to know which molecules are hot or cold, and there has been experiments that have converted information to energy using a setup similar to Maxwell's demon.

> The scientists used a high-speed camera to photograph the molecule.
> When it happened to be moving up the staircase, they let it move
> freely, but when it happened to be moving down the staircase, the
> researchers blocked its motion by inserting a virtual wall using an
> electric field.
>
> "It's like the particle is making random steps up or down, but only
> when the particle goes up the stairs, we put some wall on the stairs
> to avoid the particle falling down," Sano told LiveScience. "This is
> kind of a Maxwell's demon."
>
> As the particle moved up the staircase, it gained energy because it
> moved to a location of higher potential — akin to climbing a mountain.
> Yet the researchers never had to push the particle up the mountain
> (i.e. do work or input energy) – they simply used the information
> about which direction it happened to be moving in at any given time to
> guide the climb.
>
> **Not only were the researchers able to move the particle
> up the stairs, but they were able to precisely measure how much energy
> was converted from information.**

[experiment link](https://www.nbcnews.com/id/wbna40196095)

The question is, are knowledge and information the same thing? Claude Shannon said that information was the reduction of uncertainty. So a coin being flipped is uncertain and it landing on heads is certain and you gained information about the coin.

Does the reduction of uncertainty require knowledge or can you have the reduction of uncertainty without knowledge?

It seems with Maxwell's demon, you have to have both. The demon has to have knowledge of hot and cold molecules and when he reduces uncertainty and disorder by separating the hot and cold molecules that's information being converted to energy but what about the knowledge the demon has of what hot and cold molecules mean and how to separate them? So with Maxwell's demon, do you need to separate information from knowledge and if so does knowledge of the system expend energy separate from information?

Comment: https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/Knowledge-and-Information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say knowledge and information is separate based on Godel’s Theorem. I agree with Penrose that things like understanding and knowledge are non-computable.

Specifically, I don’t see where knowledge of the demon increases entropy like information being converted to energy.

For instance, if my car doesn’t start, I’m uncertain of the cause, it takes energy and information to reduce the uncertainty and figure out my battery is dead. When I reduced uncertainty, information increased which means information was converted to energy and the overall entropy of the universe increased and it was greater than any energy used reducing the uncertainty as to why my car didn’t start.

This is separate from knowledge of my car and the knowledge of how to look for the problem with my car. Just like the demon can reduce uncertainty by separating hot and cold molecules which takes knowledge on how to separate the molecules and knowledge of what separating the molecules means when going from disorder to order. So Maxwell’s demon doesn’t account for the metaphysical knowledge of the demon.